# openSSL key block access function?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, cryptography

I am stuck to retrieve the Key_block generated after the SSL handshake. I implemented a simple Client.cpp/Server.cpp program that is working well for exchanging encrypted data.

I would like to retrieve the key_block because I want to re-use it and perform my own encryption in another communication, but without having another handshake again.

I tried :

```
ssl->s3->tmp.key_block
```

but it retrieves an empty string (?!) and of course

```
ssl->s3->tmp.key_block_length
```

retrieves 0 value.

I call these methods just after SSL_accept(ssl) succeeds.

Once I've been able to catch this key_block, I'll need to find the encryption function used by SSL_write(...)

Hope you hear me, because the openSSL doc seems encrypted to my eyes.. =)

Comment: The key block is used only during handshake and is used to construct *several different* working keys; there is no single 'the' key or 'the' function you can use to mimic SSL_write if that's what you want. If you just want a shared secret to use for **something else**, OpenSSL versions since 1.0.1 implement rfc5707 to produce derived shared secrets; see `SSL_export_keying_material` in the `tls1.h` header file.

Comment: Thank you so much dave_thompson_085 ! I'll try to get a shared secret from these function. I struggle since a week with the openSSL doc, do you have a special bible to recommend, or did u just spend a lot of time on the subject to know this kind of stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

XY problem. You don't need this. Just open another SSL connection to the same target and it should re-use the same SSL session and therefore the same session master secret. Maybe even the same session key, but what do you care, as long as it's secure? You seem to be just trying to avoid a second full SSL handshake, but you can do that by suitable configuration at the client.

Comment: Sharing a session will use the same *master secret*; SSL/TLS actually uses multiple (4-6) session key items derived from the master secret plus the per-connection nonces. Asker is on a server which probably can't 'open' a connection without the client(s) cooperating; OTOH OpenSSL server will store and find the session for reuse by itself, while OpenSSL client needs some config or callbacks.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the correction, but I don't know what server asker is on, and neither do you.

Comment: I am running a simple TCP server. This is just a proof of concept for the moment. What I need to to is that I woudl like to use the TCP/SSL session generated informations to encrypt a stringstream beside the Tcp/ssl connexion.

Comment: A simple question to solve my problem would be :  Do you know the function that re-use the TCP/SSL session informations (master-key, etc...) to encrypt a string beside this session ?

Comment: Sorry that was jargon I could better have expanded. 'OpenSSL server' is the portion of the library (libssl.so or ssleay.dll) that implements server-side protocol for SSL/TLS, and can be called by a wide range of server apps; similarly 'OpenSSL client' is the library code called by various client apps. Q specifies `SSL_accept` which is one of the server library calls (and an important one) thus it is using 'OpenSSL server'.